# Div tags and iframes

Tags: css, html, iframe

Im looking for a way to make the content `div` expandable on click of the `iframe` to display the `iframe` content correctly, the code is:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id='outerdiv'>
    <iframe src="http://mywebsite.com" id='inneriframe' scrolling="no"></iframe>
  </div>
</div><!-- end of content -->
```

CSS is

```
#content
{
  width: 790px;
  height:auto;
  padding: 5px 55px 0;
}

#outerdiv
{
  width:790px;
  height:446px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

#inneriframe
{
  position:absolute;
  top:-268px;
  left:-230px;
  width:1280px;
  height:1198px;
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: why dont you use width:100%;and height:100% to iframe

Answer (score 0):

At first we must cleanup your CSS code:

```
#iframe{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Now we must wrote some in Jquery:

```
var iframeDoc = $('#iframe').contents().get(0);

var start = "big";
$(iframeDoc).bind('click', function( event ) {
    if(start == "big"){
        $("#iframe").animate({width:"100%", height:"100%"}, 1000);
        return start = "small";
    } else if(start == "small") {
        $("#iframe").animate({width:"100px",height:"100px"},1000);
        return start = "big";
    }
});
```

Use:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src=""></iframe>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/YuWSy/